# Target instance of JFrame inherited class

Tags: java, swing

I have a question about using `JFrame`s

(source 1)

```
import javax.swing.*;  

public class FirstSwingExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();// creating instance of JFrame

        JButton b = new JButton("click");// creating instance of JButton
        b.setBounds(130, 100, 100, 40);// x axis, y axis, width, height

        f.add(b);// adding button in JFrame

        f.setSize(400, 500);// 400 width and 500 height
        f.setLayout(null);// using no layout managers
        f.setVisible(true);// making the frame visible
    }
}
```

(source 2)

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


class FrameTest extends JFrame {
    public FrameTest() {
        JButton b=new JButton("click");//create button  
        b.setBounds(130,100,100, 40);  

        add(b);//adding button on frame  
        setSize(400,500);  
        setLayout(null);  
        setVisible(true);  
    }
}

public class Appl {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
          new FrameTest();
    }  
}
```

My question is:

in source 1 - .add, .setSize, .setLayout and .setVisible are methods of instance of 'f'.
those of methods initialize properties of 'f'.

but in source2 - add, setSize, setLayout and setVisible are methods of a certain super class.

in this source, there are not any JFrame instance. However it just works without problems.

I cannot figure it out. I discovered Container.class and JFrame.class, Frame.class But I couldn't find the part that makes JFrame instance.

Answer (score 4):

> in this source, there are not any JFrame instance

This is the incorrect assumption. In the second code base the current instance, the `this` as it were is a JFrame object. You create the instance when you call `new FrameTest()`. Since FrameTest inherits from JFrame, all instances will be children of JFrame.

Other unrelated issues:

- While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
- You'll usually not want to create classes that extend JFrame, since in doing so you are forced to create and display JFrames, when often more flexibility is called for. In fact, I would venture that most of the Swing GUI code that I've created and that I've seen does **not** extend JFrame, and in fact it is rare that you'll ever want to do this. More commonly your GUI classes will be geared towards creating JPanels, which can then be placed into JFrames or JDialogs, or JTabbedPanes, or swapped via CardLayouts, wherever needed. This will greatly increase the flexibility of your GUI coding.

Comment: Damn. I wanted to answer that XD. beat me to it :P

Comment: @ItamarGreen: sorry

Comment: thanks a lot. and your additional comment is more help for me.